# How to setup IPv6 on a Debian 11 VPS?

Tags: debian, ipv6

I have a test instance on Linode and have asked their technical support to provide me with with an IPv6 range. This is the range I obtained.

```
2600:3c03:e001:441::/64
```

How can I expose 200 global IPv6 addresses based on this range, instead of using local addresses like `fd42:42:42::1`, `fd42:42:42::2` etc?

I did some research, but I'm not entirely sure if this is the right approach.

Am I correct to believe that they should be set up like this:
`2600:3c03:e001:441::1`, `2600:3c03:e001:441::2` etc?

I have edited `/etc/network/interfaces`. And have removed `iface eth0 inet6 auto`

and then added:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
   address 2600:3c03:e001:441::1/64
   gateway fe80::1
```

After a reboot, I can SSH into the instance with the new IPv6 IP address, which seems correctly exposed to outside.

But how do I define the remaining 199 IPs? I have tried to add a second one like this:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2600:3c03:e001:441::1/64
  gateway fe80::1
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2600:3c03:e001:441::2/64
  gateway fe80::1
```

But then the system hangs.

Answer (score 1):

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2600:3c03:e001:441::1/64  
  address 2600:3c03:e001:441::2/64  
  address 2600:3c03:e001:441::3/64    
  address 2600:3c03:e001:441::4/64  
  gateway fe80::1
```

and so on....

Comment: Address can be used as often as you want

Comment: @hourman It would be very nice if you could accept my offered answer